# Self-similarity dimension for IFS or attractor of IFS

Tags: fractals, hausdorff-measure, iterated-function-system

We can have same attractor from different iterated function systems. So i wonder about self-similarity dimension concept is for IFS or its attractor. We know that when IFS satisfies the open set condition then Hausdorff dimension coincide with self-similarity dimension. And from my understanding Hausdorff dimension is unique for a set.

For example Cantor $1/3$ set, I have two IFS which are as:

First IFS: $ (f_1,f_2)$ such that $ f_1 (x) = x/3 , f_2 (x) = (x+2)/3 $ and

Second IFS: $ (g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5,g_6)$ such that $ g_i (x) = (x+(j-1))/9 , \, i=1,2,3,4,5,6, \, j=1,2,3,7,8,9 $

From first IFS I am getting self-similarity dimension is $ \log{2}/\log{3} $, and from second IFS it is $ \log{6}/\log{9}. $

And both IFS satisfies the open set conditions, so this means $1/3 $ Cantor set has two different Hausdorff dimensions. 
I don't know where I miss something.

Comment: The second IFS does not give the Cantor set. Its attractor contains points in $(1/9,2/9)$, while the Cantor set does not.

Comment: I just want to construct two IFS which has same attractor. So that I can say that we have same self-similarity dimension for this attractor if it satisfies open set condition.

Comment: Then you should modify your second IFS to be $(g_1,\dots,g_4)$ with $j=1,3,7,9$, yielding the self-similarity dimension $\log4/\log9=\log2/\log3$.

Comment: Means whenever there are two IFS for same attractor they must have same self-similarity dimension. Is any reference for this?

Comment: It is possible for two iterated function systems to have the same attractor, yet have different similarity dimensions.  For example, define the system $\{f_1(x) = x/3, f_2(x) = x/3, f_3(x) = x/3 + 2/3\}$.  This system has the Cantor set as its attractor, but the system has "similarity dimension" equal to 1.  Of course, this system fails to satisfy the open set condition, so we oughtn't be surprised.  On the other hand, as you note, if an IFS satisfies the OSC, then the similarity dimension (of the IFS) agrees with the Hausdorff dimension (of the attractor).

Comment: Regarding a reference, Hutchinson's 1981 paper is a good start.  You might also try Edgar's book *Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry*, which (if I recall correctly, discusses the similarity dimension).  Falconer's books must also touch on this somewhere, particularly the undergraduate text (*Fractals something something and Applications*---the current edition has a rendering of the Mandelbrot set on the cover).